# Deadlocks on a high load of contact inserts

Tags: drupal, contacts, webform-civicrm, email, database

We use CiviCRM 5.21.2 with Drupal 7.69 and Webform together with webform_civicrm to provide petitions. The petitions ask for address and email. So every petition signature creates a contact with email and address. Additionally every contact gets a tag and if the email is confirmed with webform_confirm_email in some cases a group.

If the load on this webform submission gets higher we face deadlocks. Some of them seem to connected to group cache and acl cache and some to email or address inserts.

I saw that the tables email and address have triggers defined for insert, update and delete that write into the table contact. For example:

UPDATE civicrm_contact SET modified_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = NEW.contact_id;

Is it possible that these triggers have something to do with at least some of the deadlocks. Or that they at least make the chance higher to run into a deadlock?

Does anybody know, why they are there? Is it necessary to update the modified_date in the table contact immediately or would it be sufficient for the system if this is done by a cron job that runs once per day?

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?  There is some new-ish code in CiviCRM that takes advantage of locking features not available in older versions of the database software, which reduces deadlocks.

Comment: It is Mariadb 10.3.22

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some smart groups that are getting re-calculated on each submission perhaps?

Here's my answer to a more general question about smart groups and performance:
[How Smart Groups Work](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/how-smart-groups-work/19774)

Comment: I am afraid, that I understand too little about the processing of smart groups to answer this question. I can say, that I deleted as much smart groups as easy possible, but there are still 18 left. If this would help I could get rid of more with some effort. We use smart groups only as mailing lists for CiviMail. So I set smart group cache timeout to 0 and there is no scheduled job, that calculates smart group cache. I would only want a specific smart group calculated on mailing creation if it is used.

Comment: Here's an easy experiment: try disabling all your smart groups (i.e. so they will be easy to re-enable). Smart group performance can be very counter-intuitive (I've added a link in my answer above to a previous spiel).